# SharePoint 2016 getting error while save site as template

Tags: site-template, site, 2016

I am getting strange issue while working with **SharePoint 2016**. I have one subsite which i need to save as site and then i need to create new site using same template.

While trying to save site as template i am getting error. I have research for same issue and found that we can't save publishing site as template but my site having team site template and i haven't activated any publishing feature in team site still getting error while saving site as template.

Anyone else having same issue in **SharePoint 2016**?

I have tried following steps with no luck.

[Save SharePoint publishing site as a template](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/how24/2013/06/13/save-sharepoint-2013-publishing-site-as-a-template/)

Comment: try to use pnp powershell, remote provisioning
https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/GetSPOProvisioningTemplate.md

Comment: You are using Publishing site template or team site template?

Comment: Hi i have mention that i am using team site template.

Comment: Have you tried to save template from SharePoint Designer ?

Comment: Cool, Whether you are able to see the Save a site template option in Site action in site setting.

Comment: From SharePoint designer it redirect to "/_layouts/15/savetmpl.aspx" page of that particular site. And from there i am getting error.

Comment: Nope. I am not able to see option to save site as template. i am access that page through URL and i think this doesn't matter because i am able to access page for same.

Comment: Make sure SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure is  deactivated in site collection feature in site setting

Comment: Is it require to deactivate publishing feature at site collection level? I need to create template of sub site and i haven't activate any publishing feature in sub site. My root site having publishing site template.

Comment: Let us Discuss in chat room

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46329/discussion-between-suriyaadevan-balu-and-dom).